# How to add task to asyncio loop inside of a django view?

Tags: python, django, django-channels, python-asyncio

I have middleware that sets up the `get_response` method as a coroutine so that another task can be run together:

```
class AsyncMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = asyncio.coroutine(get_response)

    def __call__(self, request):
        tasks = [self.get_response(request), <OTHER_ASYNC>]
        response, *other_response = asyncio.run(self.gather(tasks))
        return response

    async def gather(self, tasks):
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Inside of my django view, I need to use django channels to send a task to a worker on a PATCH request. When I try to add the task to my loop, the response completes, my model is updated, but the task is never sent to my worker.

```
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
                result = loop.create_task(channel_layer.send(
                    'model-update',
                    {
                        'type': 'update',
                        'data': {}
                    },
                ))
```

I've tried many different variations of this code. If I remove the async code from my middleware and use `async_to_sync` from asigref, everything works as expected (this is not a real option because `async_to_sync` cannot be used inside a run loop)

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Unless you're using the version 3.0 which was just released, then simply making the get_response a coroutine isn't going to help much as the the view and the chain of code leading to it are all synchronous and so will never give back control to the event loop until complete.

Comment: I'm using 2.2. What you're saying makes sense. There is no way for me to run async code inside my view then?

Comment: You won't gain anything from it as at the moment unless you use the new 3.0 which partially supports async. Only if you have core business logic elsewhere which doesn't depend on the ORM or other synchronous Django components, can you gain any value from making it async